# Problem on Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Question-
A bag contains n balls , one of which is white. The probability that A and B speak truth are P1 and P2 , respectively. One ball is drawn from the bag and A and B both assert it is white. Find the probability that drawn ball is actually white.

I did try and got this answer -
P1P2/{(P1P2 + (n-1)(1-P1)(1-P2)}

But Answer key says -
(n-1)P1P2/{((n-1)P1P2 + (1-P1)(1-P2)}

I am quite sure I get right answer but I request you guys to verify it.

Comment: To see that the official answer is wrong, note that, as $n\to \infty$, the official answer goes to $1$, which doesn't make sense.  Your answer is fine (note that it correctly goes to $0$ in the large $n$ limit).

Comment: Note that the official answer would be correct if the problem said that "all but one of the balls are white".

Comment: Or take $n=1$ where your formular gives 1 (correctly) and the official answer 0.